# How do I add email fields on a form using a button?

Tags: javascript, forms, email

Good day

I require some help with a certain issue.

I have a form which has a tab labelled "Submit". On this "Submit" form page there must be an option for the user to add additional emails his form can be CC'd to; outside of his own email entered in the first tab of the form.

It must add an email field every time the user clicks the button labelled "Add Email".

Could I create a few email fields and hide them on the form? So each time the user clicks "Add Email", one of the hidden email fields will pop up and the user can enter a desired CC address.

I hope I explained this clearly enough. Thank you for reading.

Comment: My suggestion would be is to use JavaScript to add one dynamically each time instead.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend having hidden fields and unhiding them as you may run out, it'd be better to just append the email fields every time they press the button.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. I also thought I could run into problems if the user theoretically has an insane amount of emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a onclick event for the button and, using javascript, you can append a new textbox in a container

```js
function addTxt()
{
  var cont = document.getElementById("container");
  var input = document.createElement('input'); 
  input.setAttribute("type", "email");
  input.setAttribute("value", "");
  input.setAttribute("name", "Test Name");
  cont.appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<form>
  <button onclick="addTxt()">Add</button>
  <div id="container">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: a small correction. `input.setAttribute("type", "email");` will be more appropriate

Comment: Thanks a lot my man! This worked like a charm! This was basically what I had in mind; the onclick event, just couldn't get it right. I will just now edit it so that they appear below each other. 

I'm still very new to this :) So thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that! Put a confirmation on the answer so other people can see it in case they need the solution as well